# Include python script to nw.js project

Tags: python, python-3.x, webkit, node-modules

Подскажите варианты решений.

**Глобальная задача:** Требуется включить в инсталлятор проекта (для windows) на nw.js интерпретатор python. Использую Inno Setup.

В данный момент я запускаю скрипт на python с помощью node модуля node-cmd, в моем случае на компе пользователя должен быть установлен python3 для вызова процесса из консоли. Примерно следующим образом:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Python test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      var fs = require('fs'),
        gui = require('nw.gui'),
        cmd = require('node-cmd'),
        path = require("path");
      var _dn = path.dirname(process.execPath);
      cmd.get(
        'cd ' + _dn + '\\python-test && python helloWorld.py',
        function(data, err, stderr){
         if(!err){alert('Done\n' + data)}else{alert('Error\n' + err)}
        }
      );
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*helloWorld.py*

```
print("hello world")
```

**Вопрос1:** Как можно включить интепретатор python в проект (либо в инсталлятор проекта), чтобы не заставлять пользователя устанавливать python самому?

**Вопрос2:** Может кто-то подскажет более изящное решение?

Answer (score 0):

Включил распакованный WinPython в проект (например, в директорию ./python-test/WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Zero относительно exe файла проекта). Теперь проект жирнее на 75 Mb... but it works!

Запуск скрипта теперь выглядит примерно так:

```
cmd.get(
  _dn + '\\python-test\\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.1Zero\\python-3.6.0.amd64\\python.exe ' + _dn + '\\python-test\\hello_python.py',
  function(data, err, stderr){ if(!err){alert('Done\n' + data)}else{alert('Error\n' + err)} }
);
```